# Access to protected method in java (android)

Tags: android, protected, numberpicker

I'm learning to do applications with android studio. I'm building a numberpicker programming. I want to resize my numberpiker.

To resize my numberpicker I have found a protected method called onMeasure in developer documentation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker

```
NumberPicker p_myNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
p_myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(150);
p_myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
p_myNumberPicker.onMeasure(100,100);
NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        p_number.setText(""+newVal);
    }
```

My problem is that I have an error message "onMeasure(int,int) has protected access in android.widget.NumberPicker".
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just read below the [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)) documentation and you will find:

> **CONTRACT**: When overriding this method, you must call setMeasuredDimension(int, int) to store the measured width and height of this view. Failure to do so will trigger an IllegalStateException, thrown by measure(int, int). Calling the superclass' onMeasure(int, int) is a valid use.
>
> The base class implementation of measure defaults to the background size, unless a larger size is allowed by the MeasureSpec. Subclasses should override onMeasure(int, int) to provide better measurements of their content.

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line:

```
p_myNumberPicker.onMeasure(100,100);
```

because you are violating the access scope of the method, which is not meant to be called alike this. if you really want to call it, you have to use a `CustomNumberPicker extends NumberPicker`, and call this `protected` method from within it's scope. only then the access scope would match the definition.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you resize things.  In fact calling the onMeasure of a view incorrectly will severely break things.  Since you're making it a fixed size, just give it a fixed width and height in the xml that defines the widget.  Or if defining it in code, use a dixed width and height in its layout params.